# Cannot set document.body.innerHTML of IFrame in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, iframe, innerhtml

I've looked for a cross-browser way to programmatically set the innerHTML of an IFrame.  (As in http://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/01/18/get-the-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript-crossbrowser-solution-for-both-ie-and-firefox/).  I've written some sample code (below), and  I can get it to work in Safari and Chrome, but not Firefox.  Can anyone help me figure out what I need to do instead (in a portable way)?

```
<html>
<body>

<div name=FRAME2div id=FRAME2div style="position:absolute; background-color:blue; color:black; border-color:black;border-width:0; left:100px; top:40px; width:200px; height:200px; overflow:scroll; display:block; " >
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("FRAME2div").innerHTML = '<iframe border=0 id=IFRAME2 name=IFRAME2 ></iframe>';
document.getElementById("IFRAME2").contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = '<html><body><p>NETSCAPE</p></body></html>';
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Firefox, the frame's content seems to not be recognised when no initial content has been set. The easiest method to solve this, is shown in the code below:

```
//Note: ID is not necessary for this example
document.getElementById("FRAME2div").innerHTML = '<iframe id=IFRAME2 name=IFRAME2 ></iframe>';
var doc = frames["IFRAME2"].document;

//Trigger a page "load".
doc.open();
doc.close();
//Set innerHTML of the body tag.
doc.body.innerHTML = '<p>NETSCAPE</p>';
```

Another method consists of setting the `src` property to `javascript:"&nbsp;"`, and register an one-time load event handler. This method is slightly more complex, hence I do not describe it in a deeper detail.

---

<sup>Every frame's window object can be accessed through the `frame` object, by name.</sup>

So, I recommend to use the following code:

```
frames['IFRAME2'].document.documentElement.innerHTML = "<body>...</body>";
```

`document.documentElement` refers to the root element of a document, usually `<html>`. It's possible that the `body` property of `document` isn't ready yet, when you call your current code. By referring to the root element, this problem is circumvented.

Comment: Well, I tried this, and it works in Safari, but not in Firefox.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Boris's answer is probably more pedantically correct (web developers do lots of things that you "should't"), but your answer is the one I like better, because it doesn't require me to radically restructure this web application I've inherited.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You're setting the innerHTML while there's an in-flight `about:blank` load for the iframe.  When that finishes loading, it replaces the document you modified.

If you do your modification off the iframe's onload it will work in all browsers.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I tested this code with firefox and ie and it works.
You must wait the completion of page load before modify contents.
I used the load event of body.

```
<html> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var Fill_Iframe=function(){document.getElementById("IFRAME2").contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = '<p>testo</p>';}; 
</script>
</head>

<body onload="Fill_Iframe()"> 

<iframe name="IFRAME2" id="IFRAME2" > 
</iframe> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, you should use `window.onload` in the script instead of `<body onload="...">`. Also, the `name` on the `<iframe>` isn't needed, and generally element ids are written in lowercase. In HTML5, a script `type` is optional, and using `text/javascript` is deprecated. Newer browsers will assume the new `application/javascript`, and older browsers that don't understand `application/javascript` will assume `text/javascript` when `type` is omitted.