# iframe content disappears on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am filling an empty iframe with basic HTML, using `$iframe.contents().find('body').html(contentBody);`

See: http://jsfiddle.net/UjT2b/2/

This works well on Chrome. On Firefox, I can see very briefly the content inside, but then it suddenly disappears. When I set a breakpoint on this line with Firebug, then continue running, the content stays inside. But if I set a breakpoint on the line after, it goes away.

Any clue on how to fix this?

Comment: Is that the right fiddle? I'm not seeing any thing that has to do with an iframe.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting the same result for Chrome, Safari and Firefox. I'm using Firefox 11 on Mac. Could it be something else?

Comment: The fiddle works. But I'm doing exactly the same thing in my app and it doesn't. And the weird thing is that a breakpoint solves the problem. So I have no clue on how to debug this.

Comment: Okay, it seems like putting the line in a setTimeout (even with 1 ms) fixes the problem. I would still like to understand why though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828502/cannot-set-document-body-innerhtml-of-iframe-in-firefox looks like it might be pertinent.  Apparently if you put the change in before the document finished loading, firefox overwrites with a blank at the end of the load.  Document.onload will likely serve you better than a timeout, if this is what is going on.

Answer (score 7):

I have encountered similar problem while attempting to fill dynamically created iframe. Using of iframe onload event solved the situation for me. As seen the onload solution does not work for other browsers than FF, hence the preserved standard way.

```
/**
 * Fills an iframe using data stored within textarea. Useful for creating email
 * template previews
 *
 * @param  {String} inputSelector
 * @param  {String} outputElemClasses
 * @return void
 */
function displayEmail(inputSelector, outputElemClasses)
{
    $(inputSelector).each(function(i) {
        var templateData = $(this).text();
        var $iframe = $('<iframe></iframe>');
        $iframe.addClass(outputElemClasses);
        $iframe.insertAfter(this);
        // non-firefox
        updateIframe($iframe, templateData);
        // firefox
        $iframe.load(function(e){
            updateIframe($iframe, templateData);
        })
    })
}


/**
 * Fills in target iframe using supplied data
 *
 * @param  {Object} $iframe
 * @param  {String} data
 * @return void
 */
function updateIframe($iframe, data)
{
    $iframe.contents().find('html').html(data);
}
```

Comment: this solved it for me. appears to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see your entire code, but have worked with what you gave me in a way that I would do it. There is a chance that you are not giving the script the chance to let the rest of the HTML load before it is executed and thus unpredictable things can happen. I find that if I do not wait for the window to load then the image will not show up. If you encase everything you did, like below, then you shouldn't have a problem:

```
$( window ).load( function() {

    var html = "<img src='http://www.google.fr/logos/2011/Louis_Daguerre-2011-hp.jpg' alt='image' />";


    $( "#myIframe" ).contents().find( 'body' ).html( html );

});
```

Just remember that jQuery.html() will replace all the HTML inside the element given.